# How to add relationship instances of a model on sqlalchemy's before_insert event?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to add instances of a model's relationship when an instance of this model is created.

While **before_insert** sqlalchemy event allows to set simple attribute, it does not seem to work with relationship.

Is it possible to do that with this event ? What is the standard way to achieve that ?

```
audio_project_rel = db.Table(
    'audio_project_rel',
    db.Column('project_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('audio_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('audio.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Audio(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)

class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    audiolist_filename = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    audios = db.relationship('Audio',
            secondary=audio_project_rel,
            lazy=True,
            backref=db.backref('projects', lazy=True))

@event.listens_for(Project, 'before_insert')
def get_audiolist_from_file(mapper, connection, project):    
    with open(project.audiolist_filename, 'r') as audiolist_file:
        for line in audiolist_file:
            _path = line.strip()
            audio = Audio.query.filter(Audio.path==_path).first()
            if not audio:
                audio = Audio()
                audio.path = _path 
            project.audios.append(audio) # not added
        project.name = 'somename' # added
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_events.html#session-persistence-mapper